# Error: The value Recusion function will be evaluated as part of its own definition in F#

Tags: function, recursion, f#, functional-programming

```
let rec recFunc=
    let read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    match read with
      | a when a <= 0 -> ms.ToArray()
      | _ -> recFunc  // Called recursion Function
    buffer
```

I am new in F# and I am trying to use recursive function but code showing error 
`The value recFunc will be evaluated as part of its own definition`.

I am refering [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233232.aspx) and in this page, Fibonacci function also is called again in function body. Let me know possible solutions..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

right now it's no function but a value, so let's make it into a function by adding unit `()` as it's only argument ;)

```
let rec recFunc() =
    let read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    match read with
    | a when a <= 0 -> ms.ToArray()
    |_ -> recFunc ()  // Called recursion Function
    buffer
```

Comment: Thanks.. it is working. But in Fibonacci function- let rec fib n =  if n <= 2 then 1   else fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2). they are declare function without bracket "()" and still it is working.

Comment: that's because there the `n` is it's argument - here you don't really want one so you use unit (you might know this as void - although it's a bad name) - unit only has a single type-inhabitant `()` so the brackets here are not syntax - they are are value!

Comment: maybe you can understand it better if you think `let rec recFunc (x : unit) = ...` - in F# you can use pattern-matching almost everywhere (even in function arguments) so you can write `let rec recFunc(() : unit) = ...` too but now the type annotation `: unit` is not really needed - `()` always has type `unit` - so you end up with the short form `let rec recFunc () = ...`